# Center an element based on his child XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

In my project, I have a `Canvas` inside a `Button.Template` as shown in the code below. I use this canvas to load an image, **which, unfortunately, isn't centered on the button**.

Now I'd like to have this image as the center of the grid, but I only succeed in centering the button (so I have the associated image not in the center). So I either need a way to :

- Center the button+image, based on the image
- Make the image centered on the button, so that centering on any of them is fine

  ```
  <Button Click="button1_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
      <Button.Template>
          <ControlTemplate>
              <Canvas>
                  <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" Height="120" Width="120" Source="D:\Public\Charger_boutton.png"/>
                  <TextBlock Canvas.Left="-10" Canvas.Top="125" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Préparer"/>
              </Canvas>
          </ControlTemplate>
      </Button.Template>
  </Button>
  ```

I tried putting the `HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center` inside the image (instead of the button), to no effect.

Any idea ?

Comment: Does the canvas serve some sort of purpose, and have you set `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` on the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Canvas, use a Grid

```
<Button Click="button1_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Image Height="120" Width="120" Source="D:\Public\Charger_boutton.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Préparer"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works just fine now ! I no longer needed the canvas type on this version of the code. Nice one.